# Remove specific character from a string based on hex value

Tags: c#, string, hex

While importing data from a flat file, I noticed that some of lines have embedded non breaking spaces (Hex: A0).

I would like to remove these, but the standard string.replace doesn't seem to work and had considered using regex to replace the string but wouldn't know what the regex would search for to remove it.

Rather than converting the whole string to hex and examining that, is there a better way?

Comment: Replace should handle that, can you show the code (that failed) ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why doesn't string.Replace work?

```
stringVar.Replace((char)0xA0, ' ');
```

Comment: The above changes to blank, right?  How do you completely remove it? I tried "" and '', but apparently if you have a char on the left of the replace, you have to have a char on the right side.

Comment: @NealWaters: You need to use the string version of `Replace` with `null` as the second parameter.

Answer (score 13):

```
Regex.Replace(input, "\xA0", String.Empty);
```

This ought to do it.

Answer (score 7):

string.Replace does work. Without using RegEx:

```
stringVar = stringVar.Replace("\xA0", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 3):

Would this work for you?

```
var myNewString = myCurrentString.Replace("\n", string.Empty );
myNewString = myNewString.Replace("\r", string.Empty );
```

"`\n`" is ASCII LineFeed, "`\r`" is Return.

Comment: Neither of these are the non-breaking space character A0 (160).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I misunderstood the question. Sorry. Should I delete my answer or just leave it here (I'm new to this...)?

Comment: The answer is completely wrong, nothing to correct here :-) The other guys answered correctly.