# Error reading a from file - Encoding issue

Tags: c#, csv, encoding

Im reading a CSV file that was created from **MS Excel**. When I open it up in notepad it looks ok, but in Notepad++ I change the Encoding from `ANSI` to `UTF8` and a few non printed characters turn up.

Specifically **xFF**. -(HEX Value)

In my C# app this character is causing an issue when reading the file so is there a way I can do a `String.replace('xFF', ' ');` on this?

## Update

I found this link on SO, as it turns out it is the answer to my question but not my problem. 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455218/remove-specific-character-from-a-string-based-on-hex-value-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx), Specify encoding while reading the file.

Example

```
File.ReadAllText("test.csv",System.Text.UTF8Encoding)
```

Comment: Since I have no control over where the files come from, can the encoding be determined before reading ?

Comment: How notepad does it -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Guess your unicode representation is wrong. Try this

```
string foo = "foo\xff";
foo.Replace('\xff',' ');
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good thing to "hack" the encoding. I think Tilak answer is better even if not perfect. Even better would be to know/understand what are all the encodings used in the OP's file transformation process.